# How can make django find a specific css file forSphinx?

Tags: python, css, django

I am using Sphinx to document my django application. My directory tree, based on this [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/) is:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── help
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── help
│   │       ├── _images
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── _modules
│   │       ├── objects.inv
│   │       ├── _sources
│   │       │   └── index.rst.txt
│   │       └── _static
│   │           ├── css
│   │           │   ├── badge_only.css
│   │           │   └── theme.css
│   │           ├── fonts
│   │           └── js
│   │               ├── modernizr.min.js
│   │               └── theme.js
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── polls
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── users
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.
```

The code to set the css file in the html is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_static/css/theme.css" type="text/css" />
```

This looks like an relative link, but the css is not picked up when the help file is displayed in django.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'help/index.html', {})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
                url(r'^help/', views.index, name='index'),
              ]
```

It works if the page is loaded directly into the browser.

How can I get the css file loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top of your html file specify:

```
{% load static %}
```

Your css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/theme.css' %}" type="text/css" />
```